# Lottie background changed color when loaded (expo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, lottie

I have downloaded a Lottie file but for some reason, the animation is not getting the red background and has a radial background. I haven't changed anything in it. When I upload it to the online Lottie file editor the heart renders red. What is causing this?

This is the color that is rendering

[image: This is the color that is rendering]

And this is how it is suppose to look like
[image]

Link to the online lottie animation: https://lottiefiles.com/34472-heartbeat

Here's my code:

```
<Text>

< LottieView
    source={require('../../assets/images/heartbeat.json')}
    initialSegment={68,135}
    autoPlay={true}
    loop={true}
    style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />

</Text>
```

Comment: set background to white color and test it again

Comment: My original file was with a white background, I should of mentioned that in my post. I just redownloaded one with a white background to test it again and still having the same issue